# pybind11 vs numpy for a matrix product

Tags: python, c++, python-3.x, numpy, pybind11

**Edit 2 (18 June 2018.)**

I used the `Matrix` class proposed in

http://pybind11.readthedocs.io/en/stable/advanced/pycpp/numpy.html

with a `Matrix` product that I implemented as follows :

```
Matrix product3(const Matrix &s1, const Matrix &s2) // M = M1 x M2
{
    size_t rowsM1 = s1.rows();
    size_t colsM1 = s1.cols();
    size_t rowsM2 = s2.rows();
    size_t colsM2 = s2.cols();
    assert(colsM1 == rowsM2);
    size_t resDim = rowsM1 * colsM2;
    double * ptr = new double[resDim];
    cblas_dgemm(CblasRowMajor, CblasNoTrans, CblasNoTrans, rowsM1, colsM2, colsM1, 1.0, s1.data(), rowsM1, s2.data(), colsM2, 0.0, ptr, std::max(rowsM1, colsM2));
    Matrix res(rowsM1, colsM2, ptr);
    return res;
}
```

and in release (on the core i7 6700 HQ) the result is as follows :

[image]

It is indeed much better than with the `py::array_t<double>`'s. A graph (seconds in ordinate, square matrix size in absciss) :
[image]

Numpy is relatively a tiny bit under intel mkl. There's a significative drop for both in the size region [1500,1600], steeper for the mkl. One can note that the factor "numpy time / intel time" is decreasing as the matrix sizes increases.

On a core i7-7700K this time :

[image]

The testing python code is :

```
import Binder
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import time

rangeMin = 100
rangeMax = 2000
step = 100

X = []
intel = []
numpy = []

for size in range(rangeMin, rangeMax, step):

    X.append(size)

    m1 = np.array(np.random.rand(size,size), copy = False).astype(np.float64)
    M1 = Binder.Matrix(m1)
    m2 = np.array(np.random.rand(size,size), copy = False).astype(np.float64)
    M2 = Binder.Matrix(m2)

    M = Binder.Matrix(size,size)
    N = np.array([size,size])

    #M.print()

    loopSize = 50

    start_time = time.time()
    for x in range(1, loopSize):
        N = m1 @ m2
    time_elapsed = (time.time() - start_time)/loopSize

    print("Size =\t" + repr(size) + "\tnumpy Time =\t" + repr(time_elapsed))
    numpy.append(time_elapsed)

    start_time = time.time()
    for x in range(1, loopSize):
        M = Binder.product3(M1,M2);
    time_elapsed = (time.time() - start_time)/loopSize

    print("Size =\t" + repr(size) + "\tintel Time =\t" + repr(time_elapsed))
    intel.append(time_elapsed)

fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)

ax1.scatter(X, numpy, s=10, c='b', marker="s", label='numpy')
ax1.scatter(X, intel, s=10, c='r', marker="o", label='intel')
plt.legend(loc='upper left');
plt.show()
```

---

**Edit 1 (16 June 2018.)**

I tried the same, this time with the intel mkl, replacing the `for` loop of the initial code by

```
cblas_dgemm(CblasRowMajor, CblasNoTrans, CblasNoTrans, nbRows1, nbCols2, nbCols1, 1.0, ptr1, nbRows1, ptr2, nbCols2, 0.0, ptr, nbRows1);
```

The initial code ran on a intel core i5 4570. Running all three cases this time on an intel core i7 6700 HQ just gave :

[image]

*Two remarks* :

1) Python with numpy is slower on the core i7 of my laptop than on the old core i5 desktop I used at work, for the same Python 3.6.5 32 bits. Naive c++ is a tiny bit faster. Very strange.

2) **On the core i7 the factor c++ intel mkl vs numpy is 3.41 though**

---

**Initial question**

I wrote this very naïve c++ pybind11 code :

```
py::array product1(py::array_t<double> m1, py::array_t<double> m2)
{
    py::buffer_info info1 = m1.request();
    double * ptr1 = static_cast<double *>(info1.ptr);

    py::buffer_info info2 = m2.request();
    double * ptr2 = static_cast<double *>(info2.ptr);

    unsigned int nbRows1 = info1.shape[0];
    unsigned int nbCols1 = info1.shape[1];

    unsigned int nbRows2 = info2.shape[0];
    unsigned int nbCols2 = info2.shape[1];

    assert(nbCols1 == nbRows2);

    int resDim = nbRows1 * nbCols2;

    double * ptr = new double[resDim];

    double localSum = 0.0;
    for (int i = 0 ; i < nbRows1; ++i)
    {
        for (int j = 0 ; j < nbCols2; ++j)
        {
            for (int l = 0; l < nbCols1; ++l)
            {
                localSum += ptr1[nbCols1 * i + l] * ptr2[nbCols2 * l + j];
            }
            ptr[nbCols2 * i + j] = localSum;
            localSum = 0.0;
        }
    }
    py::array_t<double> mRes = py::array_t<double>
                                (
                                    py::buffer_info
                                    (
                                        ptr,
                                        sizeof(double), //itemsize
                                        py::format_descriptor<double>::format(),
                                        2, // ndim
                                        std::vector<size_t> { nbRows1, nbCols2 }, // shape
                                        std::vector<size_t> {nbRows1 * sizeof(double), sizeof(double)} // strides
                                    )
                                );
    delete[] ptr;
    return mRes;
}
```

and I compared the average (on 500 products) times taken to perform a product of two fixed 500*500 randomly generated matrices, and got the following result :

```
python with numpy :    0.0067s
python with pybind11 : 0.7941s
```

That 118 factor surprised me. Of course, I didn't expect to beat numpy at the first try but the factor 100 between the two average times surprised me. I don't think the factor would have been drastically improved would I have used intel mkl for the `c++` part of the product, or any other library.

So I guess that this factor is mainly explained by the "conversions" of numpy arrays into `py::array_t<double>`s and the inverse conversion.

I know numpy relies on `c` code (and soon `c++` code), but I would really like to know how these conversions are done in numpy. I browsed through numpy's source code on github but didn't managed to find the "marshalling" part nor the c product part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I don't think the factor would have been drastically improved would I have used intel mkl for the c++ part of the product"

It absolutely would. Matrix-matrix product (GEMM) in MKL and similar libraries is one of the most highly tuned pieces of code ever written. It is in a completely different league than your ad-hoc loops.

Comment: Let me check with the mkl then

Comment: As usual, I have linking problems with mkl and visual studio. Ten years and nothing changed.

Comment: Linking, the bane of C++ ;-) You could also try OpenBLAS, it has similar performance to MKL.

Comment: :) Actually, it's not an mkl problem per se, see my question here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50885810/transitive-linking-in-a-python-visual-studio-context It is a problem with visual studio python projects ... (At least I think.)

Comment: Oh. Sorry, I can't help with that, I have left the VS world quite a while ago :)

Comment: I edited my question : still have a factor 3 with the mkl. No miracle. You were a bit too optimistic.

Comment: From a factor 118 to a factor 3 is pretty good though ;-) The remarks in your update are indeed strange, though. There might be something else going on still, but I don't know what.

Comment: Well yes it is better, but my first point was the "boxing/unboxing" (conversion python to c++ and c++ to python)

Comment: Yes, I understood your initial point, but it was meaningless to try to answer it because there was absolutely no indication of how large it really is. Even now, the 3x difference could still be because NumPy might use different code for the mat-mul than your MKL, for instance a different version, a differently compiled version (e.g. with `icc`), or maybe OpenBLAS. You still don't know if what you are measuring is this overhead.

Comment: If you follow the [pybind11 documentation here](http://pybind11.readthedocs.io/en/stable/advanced/pycpp/numpy.html), and do things right, no data should be copied, and the only overhead really is boxing/unboxing, which typically is negligible and no where near 3x.

Comment: I know, but did not see an exemple in their tests for `np.array(matrix_instance, copy = False)`. So I can't achieve the non-copy behaviour with `py::array_t<double>` ? I really need to use buffers ?

Comment: Ok, it's indeed much more better with the example from the document, see the second edit to my question

Comment: Last point : how can I ensure that the result (product) matrix is passed from the c++ to the python by reference and not by copy ? (I tried to return a `Matrix &` but it was crashing.)

Comment: That last point doesn't really make sense, you cannot pass a C++ class by reference to Python as these are completely different languages with completely different implementations of objects! What you want is for the buffer (memory location) that holds the matrix content not to be copied, which it already looks like it isn't. The final difference might simply be different GEMM implementations between the two. You can see what your NumPy is linked against by doing `np.__config__.show()`.

Comment: Thx a lot for your thorough answers Lucas !

Comment: On the point not making sense : how do they do it in numpy then ?

Comment: Ok, it's openblas in f77. Already compiling openblas for windows is nightmare ... :)

Comment: Note that you might, but won't necessarily, get the same performance with your own compiled version of the same library. The one compiled in numpy might have been compiled using a better compiler (icc) or just better flags than your version. But it's worth a try.

re: how they do in numpy: it's C, there is no such thing as "by reference" or even "class" in C. They do it exactly as I say it should be done in the previous comment: by using the same location in memory for the array content data. All meta-info like sizes etc. will be copied but are negligible.

Comment: Ok, as I do have intel compiler on my windows, I will try what I wanted to avoid in the first place : building openblas on windows ...

Comment: Note that I'm just using icc as an example. In reality, both of us have no idea how NumPy's OpenBLAS was compiled. My point being: I don't think you'll be able to get exactly the same performance as NumPy. You might get slightly better or worse.

Comment: Yeah, I know. I'd like at least the same perf, but I won't refuse slightly better. :) Will already try to compile what I did with icc, to see if improvments any.