# Poor performance of function calling Fortran Intel MKL dgemm vs numpy but also vs matmul

Tags: python, fortran, ctypes, intel-mkl, fortran-iso-c-binding

I am discovering fortran and ctypes in python as I plan to expose to python a fortran library using intel MKL, library that is for now called from a c libray itself being called from a c++ library ... used finally by c# ...

For a start I managed to write simple fortran code defining various matrix multiplication functions : a naive one, one using fortran's `matmul` and one using intel MKL's `dgemm`:

```
        subroutine matmultorig(M1, M2, M3, M, N, K) bind(c, name='matmultorig')
            !DEC$ ATTRIBUTES DLLEXPORT :: matmultorig
            use iso_c_binding, only: c_double, c_int
        
            integer(c_int),intent(in) :: M, N, K
            real(c_double), intent(in) :: M1(M, N), M2(N, K)
            real(c_double), intent(inout):: M3(M, K)

            M3 = matmul(M1,M2)
        
        end subroutine

        subroutine matmultmy(M1, M2, M3, M, N, K) bind(c, name='matmultmy')
            !DEC$ ATTRIBUTES DLLEXPORT :: matmultmy
            use iso_c_binding, only: c_double, c_int
        
            integer(c_int),intent(in) :: M, N, K
            real(c_double), intent(in) :: M1(M, N), M2(N, K)
            real(c_double), intent(inout):: M3(M, K)
        
            integer :: i,j,l
        
            do i = 1,M
                do j = 1,K
                    M3(i,j) = 0.
                    do l = 1,N
                        M3(i,j) = M3(i,j) + M1(i,l) * M2(l,j)
                    end do
                end do
            end do
        
        end subroutine

        subroutine matmultmkl(M1, M2, M3, M, N, K) bind(c, name='matmultmkl')
            !DEC$ ATTRIBUTES DLLEXPORT :: matmultmkl
            use iso_c_binding, only: c_double, c_int
        
            integer(c_int),intent(in) :: M, N, K
            real(c_double), intent(in) :: M1(M, N), M2(N, K)
            real(c_double), intent(inout):: M3(M, K)

            CALL DGEMM('N','N',M,K,N,1.,M1,M,M2,N,0.,M3,M)
        
        end subroutine
```

I compile the fortran using a `.bat` file (I am under windows) :

```
@Echo off

setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET "IFORT_INITIAL_FLAGS=-c -fpp"
SET "IFORT_OPTIMIZATION_FLAGS=/O3"

ifort %IFORT_OPTIMIZATION_FLAGS% %IFORT_INITIAL_FLAGS% /I"C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\compilers_and_libraries_2020.4.311\windows\mkl\include" -o test.obj test.f
ifort -dll -o mylib.dll test.obj /link /LIBPATH:"C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\compilers_and_libraries_2020.4.311\windows\mkl\lib\intel64_win" mkl_intel_lp64.lib mkl_intel_thread.lib mkl_core.lib libiomp5md.lib
```

Finally, I wrote the following python script, that I am executing from Visual Studio Code :

```
from ctypes import *
import time

import os
os.add_dll_directory(r"C:/Program Files (x86)/IntelSWTools/compilers_and_libraries_2020.4.311/windows/redist/intel64_win/mkl")
os.add_dll_directory(r"C:/Program Files (x86)/IntelSWTools/compilers_and_libraries_2020.4.311/windows/redist/intel64_win/compiler")

import numpy as np

mylib = CDLL(r"C:/path/to/the/fortran/mylib.dll")

mylib.matmultmy.argtypes = [ POINTER(c_double), 
                                POINTER(c_double), 
                                POINTER(c_double),
                                POINTER(c_int),
                                POINTER(c_int),
                                POINTER(c_int) ]

mylib.matmultorig.argtypes = [ POINTER(c_double), 
                                POINTER(c_double), 
                                POINTER(c_double),
                                POINTER(c_int),
                                POINTER(c_int),
                                POINTER(c_int) ]

mylib.matmultmkl.argtypes = [ POINTER(c_double), 
                                POINTER(c_double), 
                                POINTER(c_double),
                                POINTER(c_int),
                                POINTER(c_int),
                                POINTER(c_int) ]

# Setup    
M=500
N=500
K=500

a = np.empty((M,N), dtype=c_double)
b = np.empty((N,K), dtype=c_double)
c = np.empty((M,K), dtype=c_double)

a[:] = np.random.rand(M,N)
b[:] = np.random.rand(N,K)


# Fortran my call
start = time.time()
mylib.matmultmy( a.ctypes.data_as(POINTER(c_double)), 
                    b.ctypes.data_as(POINTER(c_double)), 
                    c.ctypes.data_as(POINTER(c_double)), 
                    c_int(M), c_int(N), c_int(K) )
stop = time.time()
print(f"Fortran my \t {stop - start}s")

# Fortran matmul call
start = time.time()
mylib.matmultorig( a.ctypes.data_as(POINTER(c_double)), 
                    b.ctypes.data_as(POINTER(c_double)), 
                    c.ctypes.data_as(POINTER(c_double)), 
                    c_int(M), c_int(N), c_int(K) )
stop = time.time()
print(f"Fortran matmul \t {stop - start}s")

# Fortran mkl call
start = time.time()
mylib.matmultmkl( a.ctypes.data_as(POINTER(c_double)), 
                    b.ctypes.data_as(POINTER(c_double)), 
                    c.ctypes.data_as(POINTER(c_double)), 
                    c_int(M), c_int(N), c_int(K) )
stop = time.time()
print(f"Fortran mkl \t {stop - start}s")

# Numpy
start = time.time()
c = a.dot(b)
stop = time.time()
print(f"Numpy \t\t {stop - start}s")
```

The result is :

```
Fortran my       0.11234903335571289s
Fortran matmul   0.023325443267822266s
Fortran mkl      0.5279343128204346s
Numpy            0.001001596450805664s
```

I was toying with the same ideas but in a python c++ pybind11 context here (same matrix sizes) :

[pybind11 vs numpy for a matrix product](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50878901/pybind11-vs-numpy-for-a-matrix-product)

where the figures where not comparable to my case now, but where at least numpy and intel mkl were somewhat in the same ballpark performance wise. Here, the function calling `dgemm` takes 500 more times that numpy matrix product. I suspect it is because of the marshalling in a minor way, and majoritarily because of the "c binding". However, I discovered all of this like two days ago, so if pros have an idea ...

Comment: You are still calling dgemm with single precision arguments - 1. is single precision. It should be double. Before you even look at the times I would VERY strongly recommend adding code that checks you get the same result in each case. If you don't get the same results the times are meaningless.

Comment: Wow, I did not understand AT ALL what you meant "last time" with double precision arguments. I thought  setting `c_double` in the fortran and in the python was indeed achieving use of double's everywhere ...  What am I doing wrong ...

Comment: 1.0 is a default precision constant in Fortran. Default precision is almost always something that looks very like IEEE single precision. All arguments to DGEMM should be double precision, not just the variables but the constants as well - there is no magic promotion to double.

Comment: Also note in ancient history I did notice that the very first call to MKL took appreciably longer than any other, presumably loading the library or similar setup. Once you are sure the answers are the same in each case I would swap the call to Numpy and mkl round and see if it makes any difference. But also note it is a long time since I last looked at this.

Comment: Christ I am stupid ... `0D`, not `0.`. It indeed changed everything, and yes, the results are equal up to last digits. I am really sorry.

Comment: Actually, you want `0._c_double`. I get 2 ms with `matmul()` and 1.2 ms with MKL.

Comment: @VladimirF Ok ... What's the difference between `0D` and `0._c_double` ?... (Don't shout on me please ... :))

Comment: It will be the same almost always. One is Fortran `double precision` and the other is the `real(c_double)`. The could be different if one uses flags to promote Fortran real types similar to the `-double_size=16` flag.

Comment: Sorry, the flag was just an example, the correct syntax would be `-double-size 128`.

Comment: Ok, I understand. Thank you both VladimirF and IanBush !

Comment: Did you mean to write your `matmultmy` routine to be purposefully inefficient?  Fortran is a column-major language.

Comment: @steve Exactly. ;) I know. But always forget.